# Mocking RestTemplate#postForObject in a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, resttemplate

Given a class `EncoderService` which has the following `createNewStream` method and a bunch of constants used in the method, how can I use `mockito` to write a unit-test for the `createNewStream` method:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> createNewStream(Long channelId) {
    String url = IP + VERSION + serverName + VHOSTS + vhostName + APP_NAME + appName + STREAM_FILES;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    headers.setAcceptCharset(Arrays.asList(Charset.forName(UTF_8)));

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String udp = "udp://" + "localhost" + ":" + "1935";
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", STREAMS + appName + channelId);
    map.put("serverName", serverName);
    map.put("uri", udp);
    HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

    HttpStatus statusCode = null;
    try {
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, Object.class);
        statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        map.put(MESSAGE, "successful");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, statusCode);
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        map.put(MESSAGE, e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the repetition, and to explain what aspects of the function you want to test, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Otherwise, for the purpose of asking a comprehensible question you should have gotten rid of all those static declarations above keeping your example as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RestTemplate` is a class, not an interface, and it implements the actual HTTP transport. Both are standing in the way of writing a testable method. On top of that the fact that you are constructing an instance of a class that has side effects on the OS level rather than getting it injected does not help the case. So the way to solve it is:

- write your method based around an interface rather than an implementation, `RestOperations` in this case
- inject an instance implementing `RestOperations`, e.g. an instance of `RestTemplate` for production, via a constructor argument (preferred), method argument or via a `Supplier<RestOperations>` defined as a field on the class
- substitute an actual instance with a test implementation or a mock in test. I guess it is easier to go for a `Mockito.mock(RestOperations.class)` because `RestOperations` just like all other Spring interfaces defines way too many method for writing a test implementation manually

So in `EncoderService` you can have:

```
private final RestOperations restClient;

public EncoderService(RestOperations restClient) {
  this.restClient = restClient;
}

public ResponseEntity<Object> createNewStream(Long channelId) {
  ...
  ResponseEntity<Object> response = restClient.postForEntity(...
  ...
}
```

And then in `EncoderServiceTest`:

```
ResponseEntity<Object> expectedReturnValue = ...

RestOperations testClient = mock(RestOperations.class);
doReturn(expectedReturnValue).when(testClient).postForEntity(any(), any(), anyClass());

EncoderService service = new EncoderService(testClient);
// use the service
```

For the other two cases the test setup is exactly the same, just you would pass the instance into the method call instead of constructor or overwrite the supplier on the `EncoderService` instance to return the `testClient`.

I have answered a very similar question about `ProcessBuilder` which also has side effects on the OS level and was constructed directly in the method under test here [Error trying to mock constructor for ProcessBuilder using PowerMockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951537/error-trying-to-mock-constructor-for-processbuilder-using-powermockito/49953605#49953605) You can apply exactly the same tactics.